# PCA or Linear Discriminant Analysis ? Classification Problem in QoS

Tags: python-3.x, networking, classification, pca, qos

I'm working on a `classification` problem related to the marking of `ip/tcp packet`, the classes are Best Effort and Non Best Effort; I'm using `Python` language. I have selected these features: Protocol, Length of the packet, Port number used for source and destination, Ip addressess from source and destination, flag not fragment and the ECN field, everything to know a possible classification for the `DSCP field`.

My idea is to apply a dimensionality reduction for reduce the space where I'm working and see if it can improve my results (using Algorithms like Random Forest, Naive Bayes, SVM). 
For now I have used only `PCA` that creates  new axes and from them I can see the percentage of each variables considered respect to the beginning point.

However I have seen something related to the `LDA` and it maximes the variance according to the label, so it is `supervidsed learning` while PCA is `unsupervised`.

Finally what do you suggest to me, how can I proceed ? Cause I do not know when I have to use PCA for improving classification results and when LDA . And if is correct to use them.